# SSL certificate without a domain

Tags: node.js, ssl, apache2

I have a bunch of node.js apps serving information to an apache site via websockets (ws://). The site itself **doesn't have a domain name** and is accessed through its IP address (that's non-negotiable, unfortunately...)

The problem is the following :

- Without a secure connection, browsers will block the ws://
     traffic, so **I have to use SSL** and secure websockets wss://
- Without a domain name, I cannot secure the connection except by
     generating a self-signed certificate.
- Self generated certificates are not trusted by browsers and
     display an error 'certificate not trusted...'. Last chrome update
     made it even more annoying to get through the message.

In addition to that, the **IP changes regularly** and is sent to the users (2-3 people) when it happens. So a certificate issued for a specific IP wouldn't be ideal (if it's free I can deal with the hassle of refreshing the cert).

Does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately, you're probably out of luck. The problems you describe can be resolved with a domain name... if doing that is impossible, your only real option is a self-signed cert that would need to be regenerated and accepted by clients for each IP change. If I may ask, why are you unable to use a domain name for the site?

Comment: If it is a bare IP, I am curious as to why buying a domain name and pointing it at that IP is a problem. That's how most of the world does it. Though the ever changing IP would be a headache for having a cert for your server.

Comment: Why are the browsers blocking the socket without using ssl? Are there any restrictions on the network configurations or is it your choice?

Comment: If you only have a user or two, you could create your own CA, and have each person install it on their browser. You would still need to update the cert every time the IP changes though. https://www.google.ca/search?q=create+your+own+ca

Comment: @matteospampani : It seems to be default behaviour, not the first time I have the problem.

Comment: @xShirase for example [chat.socket.io](http://chat.socket.io/) works without ssl, and also my dummy example without domain works [link](http://54.243.255.197:8080/). Are you using socket.io?

Comment: @matteospampani yep I am, but the site is not served by node.js, but by apache. The websocket is considered insecure and falls back to xhr-polling thanks to socket.io magic. wss solves the problem ;)

Comment: @CarCzar : Make it an answer and I'll accept it as you gave me the least troublesome option! It works perfect and will satisfy our need for extensive privacy.

Comment: @xShirase ok now I understood the problem, I tought it was served directly by nodejs. I agree with CarCzar solution and build your own CA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have a user or two, you could create your own CA, and have each person install it on their browser. You would still need to update the cert every time the IP changes though. google.ca/search?q=create+your+own+ca