# How to create a SSL certificate for a host without domain?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, https, dns

I am testing and debugging a system where application A submits a POST request to a URL when some event occurs. One of my programs, application B, must react to this event.

Application A requires that the URL uses HTTPS. I don't want to use a self-signed certificate because it may cause problems (`curl` complains about the self-signed certificate when I test it locally).

Letsencrypt can create a SSL certificate for free, but requires a domain. This is a problem for me because application B runs on a virtual machine. Whenever the machine is restarted, it gets a different IP address. Currently, there is no domain associated with that machine (i. e. you can only access it via a URL like `http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/`).

Is there a way to use a non-self-signed certificate for an application without domain (i. e. one that runs on a URL like `http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/`)? If not, what is the easiest way to make a Spring boot application (application B) support a non-self-signed SSL certificate?

There is one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25688632/ssl-certificate-without-a-domain) suggesting to create one's own certificate authority and installing it on all machines that access the URL. This is not an option for me because I have no control over application A.

**Update 1:** Application B runs on an EC2 instance in AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Letsencrypt can create a SSL certificate for free, but requires a domain. This is a problem for me because application B runs on a virtual machine. Whenever the machine is restarted, it gets a different IP address.

It does not matter if the IP changes since all what is checked is the domain name. Thus, if the machine gets a new IP address you need to update the DNS to point to this new domain name.

In general the client will check if the subject/SAN of the certificate matches the domain in the URL. It is not possible to get a certificate which is generic enough to cover all the IP addresses you could get. Thus, having your own fixed domain name with a dynamic IP address behind it is the way to go if you want to use normal clients to access the site.